# What methods should I have JUnit tests for - How to mock methods with many dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am new to JUnit, and do not know which methods should have tests and which should not. Take the following example:

```
public List<Site> getSites(String user)
{
    SiteDao dao = new SiteDaoImpl();
    List<Site> siteList = new ArrayList<Site>();
    ServiceRequest rq = new ServiceRequest();
    rq.setUser(user);

    try
    {
        ServiceResponse response = siteDAO.getReponse(rq);
        List<String> siteNums = response.getSiteNums();

        if (siteNums != null && !siteNums.isEmpty())
        {
            List<DbModelSite> siteInfo = dao.getSiteInfo(siteNums);

            if (siteInfo != null && !siteInfo.isEmpty())
            {
                siteList = SiteMapper.mapSites(siteInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return siteList;
}


public static List<Site> mapSites(List<DbModelSite> siteInfo)
{
    List<Site> siteList = null;

    if (siteInfo != null && !siteInfo.isEmpty())
    {
        siteList = new ArrayList<Site>();

        for (DbModelSite temp : siteInfo)
        {
            Site currSite = mapSite(temp);
            siteList.add(currSite);
        }
    }

    return siteList;
}


public static Site mapSite(DbModelSite site)
{
    Site mappedSite = null;

    if (site != null)
    {
        mappedSite = new Site();

        mappedSite.setSiteNum(site.getSiteNum());
        mappedSite.setSpace(site.getSpace());
        mappedSite.setIndicator("Y");
    }

    return mappedSite;
}
```

It is pretty trivial to come up with a unit test for both the `mapSites()` and `mapSite()`methods, but where I am having trouble is with the `getSites()` method. Does it make sense to unit test this method? If so, how would I go about doing so? It seems that this would require quite a bit of mocking, and as I am very new to JUnit, I have not been able to figure out how to mock all of these objects.

So my question is really two fold:

1. How do you determine if a method needs to be unit tested?
2. How does one unit test a complex method which requires a large amount of mocking?

Comment: Yes, it should be unit tested too, ideally at least all `public` methods should be unit tested as they define somehow the contract of your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to test that method.

The first thing to be able to test it, would be to use dependency injection. If the method creates its own SiteDao instance using new, there is no way you can tell the method to use another, mock instance of SiteDao.

So, read on dependency injection, and use it. Basically, it boils down to

```
public class MyService {

    private SiteDao siteDao;

    public MyService(SiteDao siteDao) {
        this.siteDao = siteDao;
    }

    // use the siteDao passed when constructing the object, instead of constructing it
}
```

That way, when testing your service, you can do

```
SiteDao mockSiteDao = mock(SiteDao.class);
SiteService service = new SiteService(mockSiteDao);
```

Here's one pice of advice that is not directly related to your question, but will make your code much simpler, and thus easier to test, too:

1. Never return null from a method returning a collection. Return an empty collection to signal "no element".
2. In general, don't accept null as a valid method argument value, especially if the argument is a collection.
3. Corollary of 1 and 2: by following these principles, you never need to check for null or emptyness of a collection. Just use it directly.

This will reduce the number of `if (siteNums != null && !siteNums.isEmpty())` cluttering your code, and you'll have way fewer branches to test, too.

Note that all sane libraries (the JDK methods, JPA, etc.) follow these principles. A JPA query will never return a null list for example.

Also, don't swallow an exception by just printing its stack trace and returning an empty list, as if nothing bad happened. Let the exception propagate so that you can notice and fix the bug.

Just imagine that this method is a method returning the number of cancer tumors found by a medical analysis system. Would you really like the system to tell you that you're in perfect health, whereas the system was in fact unable to do its job due to an exception? I would really prefer the system to say "I'm out of order, use another machine to be sure".

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. As far at the null checking goes, that makes sense if they are my methods, but take `siteNums` for example. This is returned from an external service, so I do not know if they have sufficient null checks, so I want to check the response on my side just in case I get a null returned from that service. I actually took most of the exception logic out to make my post shorter, but helpful advice either way.

Comment: It's returned from ServiceResponse, itself returned by SiteDao, which I expect are your classes. These classes should obey the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of unit testing is to ensure that each "unit" (which is usually a method) can be tested in isolation so you can test that for given input you receive an expected output, so to answer your questions:

1. I should say all public methods *should* be unit tested
2. If you are doing too much in your method that you need to mock lots then you probably want to break the functionality out into another class

Going back to your example there are a couple of things to be wary of if you want to unit test:

- `new` - anytime you use this keyword in a method you will find it difficult to mock that object. In some cases (like `ServiceRequest`) it's fine but in others such as `SiteDao` you'll have problems.
- Static methods - same thing, with `SiteMapper.mapSites(siteInfo)` you will find it difficult to mock

You can use libraries such as [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to mock `new`, `private` and `static` methods but I personally try to avoid that.